# Diesel's attribute `primary_key` is currently unknown to the compiler

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I'm trying to use the `#[primarykey()]` macro in Diesel but am getting an error that it is unknown. From what I have found, adding `#![feature(primary_key)]` should solve the issue, but it doesn't.

**lib.rs**

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;
extern crate dotenv;

pub mod schema;
pub mod models;

use diesel::prelude::*;
use diesel::pg::PgConnection;
use dotenv::dotenv;
use std::env;

pub fn establish_connection() -> PgConnection {
    dotenv().ok();

    let database_url = env::var("DATABASE_URL")
        .expect("DATABASE_URL must be set");
    PgConnection::establish(&database_url)
        .expect(&format!("Error connecting to {}", database_url))
}
```

**models.rs**

```
#![feature(primary_key)]

extern crate diesel;

#[derive(Queryable, Debug)]
#[primary_key(user_id)]
pub struct User {
    pub user_id: i32,
    pub email: String,
    pub password: String,
    pub bio: String,
    pub verified: bool,
}
```

I've also tried adding `#![feature(primary_key)]` to the top of `lib.rs` without any luck.

Using Rust 1.26.0-nightly (80785a547 2018-03-30)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `primary_key` attribute is only applicable when deriving `Identifiable`:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;

mod schema {
    table! {
        users (user_id) {
            user_id -> Int4,
            email -> Text,
        }
    }

    #[derive(Debug, Identifiable)]
    #[primary_key(email)]
    pub struct User {
        pub user_id: i32,
        pub email: String,
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

I believe you could also just change your primary key in your schema definition (`users (user_id)`).

Comment: That worked. Note for future people who find this question/answer: Since my schema and models were in two different files, I had to add `use schema::{users};` to the top of models.rs to get it compile.

Comment: Would adding the primary key in my schema definition have the same effect? Are there differences in either approach?

Comment: @crashspringfield could you suggest how I could clarify the statement  in the answer which I thought already addressed your comment: *I believe you could also just change your primary key in your schema definition (`users (user_id)`)*?

Comment: Sure. So I get that schema.rs is generated from models.rs. Does #[primary_key(user_id)] generate a schema where the primary key is `user_id` instead of `id`? I've been manually updating my schema to represent changes I've made to my models, so that could be where my confusion arises.

Comment: @crashspringfield *I get that schema.rs is generated from models.rs* — it is not. Generally, the schema definition in the Rust code reflects the schema of the database. In my answer, it's the `table!` macro, which is just "hard coded" into the source. [You normally generate the schema from the DB: `diesel print-schema > src/schema.rs`](http://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started/). Your Rust structs are subordinate to the schema.

Comment: This probably changed in a later release, but now you need `#[diesel(primary_key(email))]`